# Servlet release on app server

Tags: java, rest, servlets

Is there a way to check if the servlet is already been released to memory of the appserver.
say for example I run the doPost method and successfully output the json data that I asked from the server. Is it already been released to the memory? if not, is there a way to invoke the release of the servlet?

Thanks,

okay so this what I do, basically I am calling a client side POST from the javascript to

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "GetSampleServlet",
        data : "{}",
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(response) {
            $("#employee_per_tm_table_view").html("");
            var resultsArray = (typeof response) == 'string' ? eval('('
                    + response + ')') : response;
}
```

THEN there is a doPost Method on the servlet.
       CallableStatement st = conn.prepareCall(sql);

```
        ResultSet data;
        data = st.executeQuery();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.getWriter().write(ResultSetConverter.convert(data).toString());

        try {
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.getWriter().write((e).toString());
    } catch (JSONException f) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.getWriter().write((f).toString());
    } catch (NullPointerException g) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.getWriter().write((g).toString());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about "released to memory". What does "release of the servlet" mean?

Comment: I mean, is it release by the appserver once it output the json data I requested from the server? so was cleared from the heap?

Comment: That would be quite inefficient, don't you think? There's no need to garbage collect servlet instances. Why do you think there is?

Comment: Hi @Kayaman what I mean is that I want it to be released on the instace pool from the app server/ servlet container. Is that possible?

Comment: The problem is when I have first 10 tries of calling the servlet it is very quick to response, but when I tried to call it after 10 ties it starts to slow down, so I was just asking if after that service call it was already been released?

Comment: You should find out what the real problem is. Most likely your code is doing something silly. Profile the application or edit the question and post relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not closing your `ResultSet` (although closing the statement should close the resultsets as well, but you never know with  the drivers). You're ignoring two possible exceptions, which is just begging for problems (what if closing the statement throws an exception telling you to close the resultset first?).